# Correct using of try/catch clause on database execution

Tags: c#, error-handling, database, postgresql

When a statement to a DB returns null, I am catching it this way:

```
private int GetLastRoundNumber(int period)
{
    int id;
    try
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(_entwConnection))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT roundNumberId FROM race.folders WHERE period = @period ORDER BY roundNumberId DESC LIMIT 1;";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("period", period);
                return id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException e)
    {
        Debug.Write(e.Message);
        Debug.WriteLine("Because of a new period, started with 1 again. Period: " + period + ".");
        return id = 1;
    }
}
```

So to this codepart my questions:

1. Is it okay to have the try/catch block outside the using statement
   block?
2. Is there a better way to handle the exception?
3. Do I need to hit the catch block?

I am asking because as I learned it by now, for me it isn't a real exception, because when a new period starts, there is no Id inside.

Is this the correct way to deal with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some quick remarks:

- Avoid writing ADO.NET code by hand; instead [use an ORM like Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).
- Why not use [`MAX()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) -- which I think is supported by PostgreSQL -- instead of `ORDER BY roundNumberId DESC LIMIT 1`?

  > ```
  > SELECT MAX(column_name)  
  > FROM table_name  
  > WHERE condition;
  > ```
- Don't put business logic in exceptions. Instead, make this method `int?
  TryGetRoundNumberId()` and let the calling code solve the issue when a null is returned.

  Or perhaps provide a default, e.g. `int TryGetRoundNumberId(int defaultValue)`, so you'll get something along these lines:

  ```
  using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
  {
      sqlConnection.Open();

      using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
      {
          // snip parameters etc.

          var result = (int?)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
          if (result.HasValue)
          {
              return result.Value;
          }
          else
          {
              return defaultValue;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Ty. Is Dapper like dotConnect?

Comment: Disagree with avoiding ADO.net; sometimes it's better to use something higher level, sometimes it's not. Depends on the use case.

Answer (score 5):

Just one short note...

> ```
> catch (NullReferenceException e)
> ```

You never want to catch this exception explicitly. 99.999% of the time its occurance means there is a serious bug in your code that can be prevented with proper null checks.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it okay to have the try/catch block outside the using statement block?

I see no apparent reason why having a `try/catch` outside of a `using` block would cause a problem as disposables wrapped by `using` blocks will be disposed once they go out of scope regardless of exception or not.

> Is there a better way to handle the exception?
>   Do I need to hit the catch block?

You could avoid that exception entirely by checking the value before trying to return it. And taking action based on what was returned.

```
private int GetLastRoundNumber(int period) {        
    using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_entwConnection)) {
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT roundNumberId FROM race.folders WHERE period = @period ORDER BY roundNumberId DESC LIMIT 1;";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("period", period);
            var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result == null) {
                Debug.WriteLine("Because of a new period, started with 1 again. Period: " + period + ".");
                return 1;
            }
            return (int)result;
        }
    }
}
```

Any exceptions in the above code should bubble up to be handled by the caller. This allows the method to have a single responsibility by not mixing cross-cutting concerns.

Comment: I'm not a fan of error flags and I find the exception should bubble up to the caller or the method should change its name to `TryGetLastRoundNumber` to clearly communicate the non-exceptional work.

Comment: Yeah, I was torn on that part and had decided to leave it in. My thought was to avoid handling it in the method on a whole. I'll include your comment in an update.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like using an exception to catch no rows

I would return to a reader

```
int id;
using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(_entwConnection))
{
    con.Open();
    using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT roundNumberId FROM race.folders WHERE period = @period ORDER BY roundNumberId DESC LIMIT 1;";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("period", period);
        using(Reader rdr = cmd.ExectuteReader()) 
        {
             if(rdr.HasRows())
             { 
                rdr.Read();
                id = rdr.GetInt(0);
             }
             else 
             { 
                id = 1;
             }
        }
    }
} 
return id;
```

just `return id` once at the end.

The `try` could be inside the `using`.  `using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(_entwConnection))` will never throw an error.

But now you you don't need to catch any errors so you don't need try catch.